# Disable redirect to '/email/verify' after user being registered

Tags: registration, fortify, laravel-10

Hi i am using laravel 10 with fortify package and i'm having troubles on trying to disable '/email/verify' after admin register users. I do not only want to display the '/email/verify' view after registration, but i still want to send the email verification code. Does anybody has an idea on how to do it?

I tried to find the return view on the register class to disable it but i didn't found it